# UIVisualEffectView vibrancy not showing on device(but showing in simulator)

Tags: ios, uivisualeffectview

I am running my test app on the 4s simulator and iPhone 4s(device).  Any ideas why the vibrant text disappears on the device?

Here are the photos with the problem:

simulator:

[image: simulator]

device:

[image: device]
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which iOS version is the device running and which the simulator ?

Comment: @Lefteris 8.1.2 on device and 8.1 on simulator

Comment: try to check if it's not disabled `if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled())`

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem too, with image view as content. Somehow I got it works after changing my image color to white (it's black before). Try changing your text color to pure white.

Answer (score 0):

I was scratching my head for the same problem. The solution has been given in the comments by @TonyMkenu : the flag `UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()` prevents the blur and vibrancy to work (rendering as an opaque very light ugly gray).